# Basic Code Restructure Query

Tags: c#

So, before I post my question, I will add a little bit of premise to it. I have written quite some code for academic purposes, but never before was it for production or an actual client.
What I would always do is this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Do all the programming here
}
```

However, now when I have to build actual software for client (a small one), I find this process tedious and hard to handle as the code grows long.

I still create separate classes and do some of the work here and there, but I think it's not the correct direction.

What am I missing? How professional developers do it?
Thanks.

**EDIT** :  This is not exactly a coding question however I still choose StackOverflow because I really want the different perspectives of the superb professionals present here. I am just an industry newbie, so I really need to start learning in the right direction.

Comment: you need to create N-tier apps, where you have Data Access Layer, Bussines Logic Layer, Presentation Layer and more, so you can create reusable and easy to maintenance code

Comment: To me, it is a good question. Three Layered/Tiered architectures often help in that manner. further I would also like to know if there are ways to do it :)

Comment: How to structure code, how to abstract/create classes, how to create functions is very open ended. There are best practices for separating work into database, logic and UI, just as there are with creating classes and functions. Being a developer isn't easy and the bigger the project the bigger the problems, you may want to consider a different career choice, no seriously. A developer who wants to be a developer should already know what you're asking or be generally aware.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I find this process tedious and hard to handle as the code grows long.

You are correct.

> I still create separate classes and do some of the work here and there, but I think it's not the correct direction.

It is the correct direction.  **Programming is about abstraction**. Properties, methods, handlers, classes, and so on, are all *abstractions*. Abstractions are useful because *they present less complexity than their implementation details*, and can therefore be understood and used effectively.  Just as you do not learn how to drive by manipulating valves and cylinders and springs and camshafts; you learn *abstractions* like brakes and gear selectors.

When you learn to drive you are handed a pile of abstractions which you must learn to use. When you are programming you are both handed a pile of existing abstractions -- variables, lists, types, and so on, are all abstractions -- but you are also expected to build your own.

> How do professional developers do it?

This is not a site to teach you how to program. This is a site for *specific* questions about *actual code*.  Professional developers do it by spending thousands of hours learning from others and practicing their craft; go get started! Come on back when you have a *specific* question about *actual code*.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing it right ! Indeed managing large programs is a hard job, you have to know how to modulate your code. You can create diagram representing your project so it will make the editing a lot easier.

Here is a link with some tools for Architecture and Modeling with Visual Studio

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ThEP7DgVAC0